ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework ' error fromTensorflow object detection api model_builder_tf2_test.py
I have a problem when using tensorflow version 2.10 and trying to get the object detection api to work.
i get this error
2024-04-22 20:39:25.792930: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2024-04-22 20:39:25.793198: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 70, in <module>
from object_detection.models import ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor as ssd_efficientnet_bifpn
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.9.egg\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 35, in <module>
from official.legacy.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_models_official-2.16.0-py3.9.egg\official\legacy\image_classification\efficientnet\efficientnet_model.py", line 30, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf, tf_keras
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras_init_.py", line 3, in <module>
from tf_keras import internal
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras_internal__init_.py", line 3, in <module>
from tf_keras.internal import backend
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras_internal_\backend_init_.py", line 3, in <module>
from tf_keras.src.backend import initialize_variables as initialize_variables
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src_init.py", line 21, in <module>
from tf_keras.src import applications
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\applications_init_.py", line 18, in <module>
from tf_keras.src.applications.convnext import ConvNeXtBase
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\applications\convnext.py", line 28, in <module>
from tf_keras.src import backend
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\backend.py", line 35, in <module>
from tf_keras.src.engine import keras_tensor
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\engine\keras_tensor.py", line 19, in <module>
from tf_keras.src.utils import object_identity
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\utils_init_.py", line 53, in <module>
from tf_keras.src.utils.feature_space import FeatureSpace
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\utils\feature_space.py", line 20, in <module>
from tf_keras.src.engine import base_layer
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\engine\base_layer.py", line 35, in <module>
from tf_keras.src.dtensor import lazy_variable
File "c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tf_keras\src\dtensor\lazy_variable.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor
ImportError: cannot import name 'tensor' from 'tensorflow.python.framework' (c:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\tfodgpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework_init_.py)
I already got it workingfor tensorflow 2.15 but needed to use 2.10 for gpu support but it does not pass the test.
i tried
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.10.0
here is alist of my packages
Package                      Version     Editable project location

absl-py                      2.1.0
apache-beam                  2.55.1
asttokens                    2.4.1
astunparse                   1.6.3
avro-python3                 1.10.2
cachetools                   5.3.3
certifi                      2024.2.2
charset-normalizer           3.3.2
colorama                     0.4.6
contextlib2                  21.6.0
cycler                       0.12.1
Cython                       3.0.10
decorator                    5.1.1
exceptiongroup               1.2.1
executing                    2.0.1
flatbuffers                  24.3.25
gast                         0.4.0
google-auth                  2.29.0
google-auth-oauthlib         0.4.6
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.62.2
h5py                         3.11.0
idna                         3.7
importlib_metadata           7.1.0
importlib_resources          6.4.0
ipykernel                    5.5.6
ipython                      8.18.1
ipython-genutils             0.2.0
jedi                         0.19.1
jupyter_client               8.6.1
jupyter_core                 5.7.2
keras                        2.10.0
Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2
kiwisolver                   1.4.5
libclang                     18.1.1
lvis                         0.5.3
lxml                         5.2.1
Markdown                     3.6
MarkupSafe                   2.1.5
matplotlib                   3.9.0rc2
matplotlib-inline            0.1.7
ml-dtypes                    0.4.0
namex                        0.0.8
numpy                        1.26.4
oauthlib                     3.2.2
object-detection             0.1
opencv-python                4.9.0.80
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
optree                       0.11.0
packaging                    24.0
pandas                       2.2.2
parso                        0.8.4
pillow                       10.3.0
pip                          24.0
platformdirs                 4.2.0
portalocker                  2.8.2
prompt-toolkit               3.0.43
protobuf                     3.19.6
pure-eval                    0.2.2
pyasn1                       0.6.0
pyasn1_modules               0.4.0
pycocotools                  2.0.7
Pygments                     2.17.2
pyparsing                    2.4.7
python-dateutil              2.9.0.post0
pywin32                      306
PyYAML                       6.0.1
pyzmq                        26.0.2
regex                        2024.4.16
requests                     2.31.0
requests-oauthlib            2.0.0
rich                         13.7.1
rsa                          4.9
sacrebleu                    2.2.0
scipy                        1.13.0
setuptools                   58.1.0
six                          1.16.0
slim                         0.1         C:\Users\besto\Documents\Local vscode\Tensorflow Object Detection GPU\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\slim
stack-data                   0.6.3
tabulate                     0.9.0
tensorboard                  2.10.1
i need the builder file to pass

Hi @Best Oscar-Osifo The core issue seems to be a conflict between TensorFlow versions and the object_detection library. While you have TensorFlow 2.10 installed, the object_detection package might be designed for a different version.Verify the compatibility of the object_detection library with TensorFlow 2.10. You can check the documentationor GitHub repository for information on supported TensorFlow versions.If you're unsure about the object_detection version, try reinstalling it.
